# skip lines for empty fields mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

```
<Header>
    <Source>J1_RETAIL</Source>
    <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
    <Sequence_Number>0</Sequence_Number>
    <Batch_ID>4383352</Batch_ID>
    <Reference_ID>04381645</Reference_ID>
    <User_ID>SAP</User_ID>
    <Password>password</Password>
    <Message_Type>SAP_DO</Message_Type>
    <Company_ID>J1</Company_ID>
    <Msg_Locale>English (United States)</Msg_Locale>
    <Msg_Time_Zone>Eastern Standard Time</Msg_Time_Zone>
    <Version></Version>
    <Internal_Reference_ID></Internal_Reference_ID>
    <Internal_Date_Time_Stamp></Internal_Date_Time_Stamp>
    <External_Reference_ID></External_Reference_ID>
    <External_Date_Time_Stamp></External_Date_Time_Stamp>
  </Header>
  <Message>
    <DistributionOrder>
        <ProcessInfo>
            <RefTextField1></RefTextField1>
            <RefTextField2></RefTextField2>
            <RefTextField3>S082</RefTextField3>
            <RefTextField4></RefTextField4>
            <RefTextField5></RefTextField5>
            <RefTextField6></RefTextField6>
            <RefTextField7>J1</RefTextField7>
            <RefTextField8>[0001333006_SAPTOMIF]</RefTextField8>
            <RefTextField9></RefTextField9>
            <RefTextField10>[ _20191223]</RefTextField10>
            <RefNumberField1>20191220</RefNumberField1>
            <RefNumberField2>34621</RefNumberField2>
            <RefNumberField3></RefNumberField3>
            <RefNumberField4>53</RefNumberField4>
            <RefNumberField5>13</RefNumberField5>
        </ProcessInfo>
        <Comment>
            <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
            <NoteCode>05</NoteCode>
            <CommentText>[00000_8769_741_82_093_965_987_456]</CommentText>
            <Visibility>0</Visibility>
          </Comment>
          <CustomFieldList>
            <CustomField>
              <Name>SiteID</Name>
              <Value></Value>
            </CustomField>
        <LineItem>
            <DoLineNbr>1</DoLineNbr>
            <ItemName>135465</ItemName>
            <Description>A</Description>
            <UpdateActionType></UpdateActionType>
            <PackageType></PackageType>
            <DoLineStatus>Released</DoLineStatus>
            <InventoryAttributes>
              <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
              <ProductStatus></ProductStatus>
              <BatchNbr></BatchNbr>
              <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
              <ItemAttribute1>R</ItemAttribute1>
              <ItemAttribute2></ItemAttribute2>
              <ItemAttribute3></ItemAttribute3>
              <ItemAttribute4></ItemAttribute4>
              <ItemAttribute5></ItemAttribute5>
            </InventoryAttributes>
        </LineItem>
    </DistributionOrder>
  </Message>
</tXML>
```

My request looks like this
In the above Request Under Distribution Order.Comment.CommentText I'm making this as an array by removing underscore and mapping to it to each row, but i'm mapping empty values too which i should not be mapped

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header = false , separator = "|" , quoteValues = false
var count = 0
fun outputMap (DistributionOrder, comment="") = 
    {
            column_1: "000000003", 
            column_2: (payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.ProcessInfo.RefTextField8 splitBy "_")[0] replace "[" with "" ,  
            column_3: if(payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.ProcessInfo.RefNumberField1 != null) (payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.ProcessInfo.RefNumberField1) else "0",
            column_4: if(payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.ProcessInfo.RefNumberField2 != null) (payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.ProcessInfo.RefNumberField2) else "0",
            column_5: "SAPTOMIF",
            column_6: payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.SalesOrderNbr default "",
    column_7: if(payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.Comment.NoteType == 'MB' and payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.Comment.NoteCode == '05')"00000" else "",
    column_8: "",
    column_9: "ST",
    column_10: "",
            column_11: (comment replace "[" with ""  replace "]" with ""default "") , 
            column_12: payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.ReferenceField7 default "",
            column_13: payload.tXML.Message.DistributionOrder.SalesOrderNbr default "",}

payload.tXML.Message.*DistributionOrder flatMap (DistributionOrder) -> 
    using (filteredComment = DistributionOrder.*Comment[?($.NoteType == "MB" and $.NoteCode == "05")])
    if (filteredComment != null) 
        filteredComment flatMap(commentObject) -> 
            using (splitCommentText = commentObject.CommentText splitBy /_/)
            splitCommentText[?($$>0)] flatMap (commentText) -> outputMap(DistributionOrder, commentText) 
    else 
        outputMap(DistributionOrder)
```

In the above example for comment text fields 4th and 5th elements are coming as empty and shouldn't be writing it in a new line(should be skipped) and it has to be skipped. Please let me me know what needs to be changed in the code

My output is looking like this

```
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF|6500054123|00000||ST||8769|J1|6500054123
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF|6500054123|00000||ST||741|J1|6500054123
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF|6500054123|00000||ST||82|J1|6500054123
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF|6500054123|00000||ST|| |J1|6500054123
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF|6500054123|00000||ST|| |J1|6500054123
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF|6500054123|00000||ST||987|J1|6500054123
000000003|0001333006|20191220|34621|SAPTOMIF|6500054123|00000||ST||456|J1|6500054123
```

In the above example for comment text fields 4th and 5th elements are coming as empty and shouldn't be writing it in a new line(should be skipped) and it has to be skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more conditions on below code to filter out the values that are not needed i.e.

```
splitCommentText[?($$>0 and trim($) != "")] flatMap (commentText) -> outputMap(DistributionOrder, commentText)
```

Note that I have included the trim command to handle spaces if any.

Comment: oim for column_8 i need to add incremental values from 01 to 07 if the value of comment text is present otherwise skip the number <Comment> <NoteType>MB</NoteType> <NoteCode>05</NoteCode> <CommentText>[00000_8769_741_82_ _ _987_456]</CommentText> <Visibility>0</Visibility> </Comment> 000000001|0|0|||01|||| 000000001|0|0|||02|||| 000000001|0|0|||03|||| 000000001|0|0|||06|||| 000000001|0|0||| 07|||| in the above example 4th element and 5th are empty so they are skipped , please suggest

Comment: you can use the index as you loop through array i.e. splitCommentText[?($$>0 and trim($) != "")] flatMap (commentText, index) and pass it to you writer function.